# How to search and replace string in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, replace, gsub

I tried the below code to search the string pattern `"]]>*/-->"` and replace it with `"*/-->"` using `gsub` function.

but instead of replacing whole string. it replaces character wise..

```
File.open('reporttestphp2.xml', 'r+') do |f1|     
  while line = f1.gets
    f1.puts line.gsub("]]>*/-->","*/-->")   
  end    
end
```

How can I replace the whole string pattern in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gsub works fine. You just need to read the file in a different way:

```
text = File.read("reporttestphp2.xml").gsub("]]>*/-->","*/-->")
File.open("out.xml", "w").write(text)
```

I hope, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by whole string pattern? If you want to use regular expressions, they are written beetween / characers in ruby, e.g. /\w+/

[Examples](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/ss/strings_5.htm)

Comment: "]]>*/-->" and "*/-->" arenot regular expressions..

I want to take it as string pattern..?

I tried using saving this in some variable 

like pattern = "]]>*/-->"

 f1.puts line.gsub(patter,"*/-->")  

but it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

To do this using a ruby regex constant,

```
gsub(/]]>\*\/-->/, '*/-->')
```